# 1 to many relationship not working by joins /Group by

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have 2 tables Transporter and Cars ,

[image]

I want to display all cars for a single Transporters in a single row

using joins I am getting cars all but in different row

[image]

I tried Group by clause but it is not working

[image]

What modifications Can i do in a query ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using GROUP_CONCAT function like:

```
SELECT t.id, GROUP_CONCAT(car_name) AS Cars
FROM Transporters t INNER JOIN cars c
ON C.t_id = t.id
GROUP BY t.id


Output:
id Cars
1  car1,car3
2  car2,car4,car5
```